# Data.table approach of simple return estimation

Tags: r, data.table

I have approximately the following `df` :

```
a  <- seq(1, 1010, 1)
b  <- seq(2,1011,1)
c  <- c(rep(1,253), rep(2, 252), rep(3,254), rep(4,251))
d  <- c(rep(5,253), rep(6, 252), rep(7,254), rep(8,251))
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

Firstly I grouped my date by columns c and d. Now I want to calculate simple returns. I apply the following code:

```
 df1<-dlply( df, .(c,d) , transform, simplereturn=c(NA,df[2:length(a),"a"]/df[1:(length(a)-1),"a"]) )
 df<-do.call("rbind", df1)
```

It seems it does not work properly and moreover, I would like to make calculations using `data.table` approach. Any suggestions?
Thank you for attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I assume to be the correct plyr solution:

```
df <- ddply( df, .(c,d) , transform, simplereturn=c(NA, a[-1] / head(a, -1)))
```

And here the equivalent data.table code:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, simplereturn := c(NA, a[-1] / head(a, -1)), by=list(c, d)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is the second time you assist me and provide very efficient codes :)